# jquery add 1 to variable on click then insert to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to have 2 buttons on a page. If u click button "addMe", then I want to add 1 to a variable? (theCount). The other button (InsertDB) I want to add "theCount" into my db.
Im able to add data to my db, but not "theCount", probly because its a "div id" and I dont know how to do it.  I have 3 files: index.php, addscript.js and insert.php

Here is my script:

index.php:

```
<?php
include "insert.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Add 1 on click, then add sum to db</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>


    <button id="addMe">Add 1</button>
    <div id="theCount"></div>

    <form method="post">
    <button id="InsertDB">Add to DB</button>
    </form>


    </body>
    </html>
    <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="addscript.js"></script>
```

addscript.js:

```
        var counter = 0;
   
        $(document).ready(function() {

             $("#InsertDB").click(function(){


             var theCount= $("#theCount").val();
              

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "insert.php",
                    data: "theCount=" + theCount,
                    success: function(data) {
                       alert("Added to DB");
                    }
                });
            });
                        
            $("#addMe").click(function(){
                counter++;
   
                $("#theCount").text(counter);
            });
        });
```

insert.php:

```
<?php
    include "db.php";

    $theCount=$_POST['theCount'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `mat`( `polse`) 
    VALUES ('$theCount')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Craig is Satoshi";
    } 
    else {
        echo "Error";
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#theCount` is a `<div>`:

```
<div id="theCount"></div>
```

And a `<div>` doesn't have a `value`, so this won't work:

```
var theCount= $("#theCount").val();
```

Instead, get the *text* of the element:

```
var theCount= $("#theCount").text();
```

Much in the same way that you already *set* the text of the element:

```
$("#theCount").text(counter);
```

Comment: So what should i Write instead of <div id="theCount"></div> ?

Comment: @EmilSøreng: Well, if you want it to be something other than a `<div>` then you can make it whatever element you like.  Though the element you choose may change this answer.  For example, if you make it an `<input>` then you would get/set its value with `.val()` instead of `.text()`.